# Custom popup menu in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a custom control in vb.net, which behaves like vb6 popupmenu & it acts like form show dialog . Popup menu filled dynamically & my O/P depends only upon click event result of popupmenu.

By using context menustrip  problem is click event of context menustrip is raised after all events of form which calls context menustrip . Hence I cant continue rest part of the program in Mainform using context menustrip itemclicked result.

1. My Main Form MouseUp is Called
2. Inside MouseUp Context Menu Is shown
3. After Show of Context Menu Strip the next line of Main Form MouseUp Continues result obtained from `ContextMenuStrip_ItemClicked`
4. `ContextMenuStrip_ItemClicked` have so many other functions and codes which cannot be replaced outside of it

Code:

```
 Private Sub ChangeLayer(ByRef X As Double, ByRef Y As Double, ByRef D As String, ByRef T As Integer)''*****Change Layer Called in MouseUp Event of MainForm
            Dim A As String
            Dim objDrawingPoint As New Drawing.Point
            Dim cms As New ContextMenuStrip
            DeleteFlag = False
            'A = M_PlaceLayer.Text
            A = PlaceOn.Text
            If T Then
                M_SelLayC(0).Enabled = False : M_SelLayC(1).Enabled = False
                M_SelLayS(16).Enabled = False : M_SelLayS(17).Enabled = False
                CompLayer(0).Enabled = False : CompLayer(1).Enabled = False
                SolderLayer(16).Enabled = False : SolderLayer(17).Enabled = False
            End If
            '' M_PlaceLayer.Text = StrAnsi(D)
            PlaceOn.Text = StrAnsi(D)
            m_LayerFlag = False
            objDrawingPoint = ViewPicture.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
            With objDrawingPoint

                cm_FO.Show(ViewPicture, New Point(.X, .Y))'''**Context MenuStrip Show() 


            End With

            '''''Depends on Result of ItemClicked of cm_FO contextmenustrip below code works

    '******************************************************

    'Code Below Works with result of Context MenuStrip ItemClicked 

    '******************************************************

    '         M_PlaceLayer.Text = StrAnsi(A)
            PlaceOn.Text = StrAnsi(A)
            If T Then
                M_SelLayC(0).Enabled = True : M_SelLayC(1).Enabled = True
                M_SelLayS(16).Enabled = True : M_SelLayS(17).Enabled = True
                CompLayer(0).Enabled = True : CompLayer(1).Enabled = True
                SolderLayer(16).Enabled = True : SolderLayer(17).Enabled = True
            End If
    '****************************************************
        End Sub
```

Comment: There are too many (undefined) variables and what you are after exactly is not completely clear to me. You want to create a popup; usually for doing that you can go really simple (MessageBox) or create a new Form. I understand that you want to create a new Form but I am not getting the problem. Are you saying that you cannot move between events in both forms? Please, tell the exact elements you want in the popup (e.g., menuStrip), when it is expected to appear (e.g., every time the user clicks...) and what are the exact problems you are facing (e.g., not being able to trigger this...).

Comment: You cannot send an email with your question such that I can solve it for you?! Please, don't do it again. If you want help HERE, reply HERE and update HERE your question such that anyone HERE can help you. This is not a private solve-my-problem service providing. Redo your question and wait for help HERE.